# IFormFile is not mapping to a model containing it on multipart/form-data request

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, axios

I have a `multipart/form-data` request being sent from `React` application via `axios` to `ASP.NET Core Web API`. Here is a part of a payload:

[image]

Here is the request model from back-end (**Photos** interests us here):

[image]

[image]

And here is the response I get from the server:

[image]

Why does not it map to `Photo`?